# Saving a file with Javascript in S60v3 mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, symbian, s60

I'm busy experimenting with [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/) and trying to get it to run on my Nokia E51, which uses S60v3. The browser is [based on webkit](http://opensource.nokia.com/projects/S60browser/), which **should** mean that I'd be able to get it to work, but no luck so far.

Does anyone have any experience with saving files locally on this platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I skimmed through the source of TiddlyWiki. For its file operations it is using the [jQuery.twFile plugin](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html) which in turn uses a custom Java applet on Webkit-based browsers. The S60 browser does not support java applets so I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: I have to agree with you, sadly. There are just too many layers between JS and the filesystem to code around it.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong here but a quick look at the widget training course on forum Nokia makes it seem like file system access from JavaScript isn't available on S60.

http://www.forum.nokia.com/Tools_Docs_and_Code/Documentation/Web_Technologies/

It really look like you're supposed to retrieve persistent data from the network.

I would hope the web browser cache allows you to query remote data several times while only transfering it once.

Comment: Widgets and the Web runtime are only available from 3rd Edition FP2 onwards (and some firmware updates to 3rd FP1 devices), after the E51.

I'm not aware of any way to save files locally from the browser.  You'll certainly be able to with Qt WebKit in the not too distant future (also 3rd FP1 onwards only) but that's a very heavyweight solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my E51 I am able do download files the old-fashion way: A simple link to a file with a fitting mimetype.

Comment: Yeah I can download files no problem. Check out TiddlyWiki -- it's a great piece of software! -- it saves itself by replacing it's own html file. That's what I was trying to achieve.